# Internal Error #1417161

Tags: batch-file

I wrote a batch script below which is supposed to extract all the zips from one directory to another, then rename all the files that do not have .zip extension to .zip and finally re-zip the top level directory.

When i run the script it seems that it's not able to find the zip files in the source directory - it spits out 2 different errors 
Internal Error #1417161 and
System ERROR:
The system cannot find the file specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the file specified.

I am using 7zip to extract and re-zip the archives, also all the zips are password protected

```
@ECHO ON
set src_folder=I:\directory1
set dst_folder=E:\directory2
set pass=CyZySvFqfbMm

for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (File-List.txt) DO (
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x -p%pass% -o"%dst_folder%\%%~ni" 
"%src_folder%\%%i"
CD "%%~ni"
REN . .zip
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip "..\%%i" .zip -p"%pass%"
CD..
RMDIR /S /Q "%%~ni"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Despite not quite understanding your problem or goal and without the opportunity to test I have nonetheless decided to give this a shot.

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "exe_dir=%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip"
Set "src_dir=I:\directory1"
Set "dst_dir=E:\directory2"
Set "zip_pwd=CyZySvFqfbMm"

If Not Exist "%exe_dir%\" Exit /B
If Not Exist "%src_dir%\" Exit /B
CD /D "%dst_dir%" 2>Nul || Exit /B

For /F "UseBackQ Delims=" %%A In ("File-List.txt") Do (
    "%exe_dir%\7z.exe" x "%src_dir%\%%~A" -p%zip_pwd% -o"%%~nA"
    For %%B In ("%%~nA\*") Do If "%%~xB"=="" Ren "%%~B" "%%~B.zip"
    "%exe_dir%\7z.exe" a -tzip "%%~A" -p%zip_pwd% "%%~nA\*"
    RD /S/Q "%%~nA"
)
```

*You may, if you're only wanting to archive the `.zip` files in the top level of the extraction location, change line `14` to `"%exe_dir%\7z.exe" a -tzip "%%~A" -p%zip_pwd% "%%~nA\*.zip"`.
Apologies if I have misunderstood or made any errors.*